# How to use existing ROS package to build my own self navigation robot?

Tags: mobile-robot, gazebo, ubuntu, gazebo-simulator, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have designed a differential drive robot similar to Turtlebot in solidworks and launched it in Gazebo successfully after developing a URDF model out of it. I want to simulate the robot in gazebo for self-navigation using ROS navigation stack. I want to use the existing ROS stakes developed for robots like Turtlebot but i cant get clear idea about how to proceed with this. Can anyone direct me to the resources.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223268/how-to-use-existing-ros-package-to-build-my-own-self-navigation-robot?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2015-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The newly released book has good chapters that go through that systematically

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024736.do

I am not involved in it in any way, I have just read it.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0